# How to solve absolute value equations using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, equation, equation-solving, computer-algebra-systems

Given the equation |x - 5| + |y| = 5, how can one solve it using SymPy?

If I'm using a combination of solve() and Abs() it gives me this error

> solving Abs(x - 5) when the argument is not real or imaginary

But, at the beginning of my session I wrote down that

```
x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z', RealNumber = True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I've found out, what was the problem. The declaration was wrong, so I had to change it to the form

```
x, y, z = symbols('x y z', real=True)
```